# Difficulty importing my live site to local

Tags: database, sql, localhost, staging

Im using local by flywheel, Here are the steps i have taken so far:

1. Installed local by flywheel and created a site called stage
2. Downloaded the website from CPanel and also the SQL database
3. Imported the database in admirer (but the links are all the same, How can i change them?)
4. Deleted the 'wp_content' folder in the flywheel site and added the 'wp_content' folder from my wordpress site there instead
5. Set the theme as the old one and reactivated all of the plugins

And i still dont have any of the data showing an none of the styling either. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: If you've got all the files and the site database then that should be enough to copy the site, as all the posts are in the database, and the styling is in the theme (and possibly the database too depending on which plugins you're using). Do you definitely have the database imported correctly and set up to use with your WordPress site? If you want help with the flywheel process though you might have to ask them. Is it definitely the same version of WordPress core, in case any changes in that (e.g. jQuery version) have broken your site's styling?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your domain links in your database.

See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/384023/202168

Answer (score 0):

Above(Sunil Jaiswal's) solution will definitely work, But if you find any trouble to change URL using that tool then you can also try this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

But keep in mind that **don't add last forward slash**

For Example
Find URL http://www.oldsite.com
Replace URL http://localhost/newsite